# Is it possible to validate model instance with Sequelize before saving it using model constraints?

Tags: javascript, validation, sequelize.js

I need to validate model instance before saving it in the database. I was thinking [Model build](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-build) method might be of a use, but it's not. Constraints and types are not checked, so if I'm, for instance, trying to save a string in an integer field, that passes.

I guess I wouldn't be able to check `unique` and `foreign key` constraints because of different validation and saving times, but that's OK.

Comment: You can add validation for a field in model. I think Regex is good enough for validating integer or string or any pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it and it works. However, since most of my validations will only check for types, is there any way I can include some sort of default validation when doing `build` and `validate`? See this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1431

Comment: I mean you want to validate before database operation,isn't it?